# How to create multiple copies of ImageView object programmatically?

Tags: android, imageview, clone, inflate

I have an ImageView object, *R.id.tile*, defined in my XML layout, and what I'm trying to do is create clones of it and place each of them at different coordinates.

This is what I have so far:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {   super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.board_layout);
        layout = (AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.board);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tile);
        View[] tiles = new ImageView[9];
        for (int i = 0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
            tiles[i] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tile);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                tiles[i+j].setX((float) 32*2*i);
                tiles[i+j].setY((float) 34.39*2*j);
            }
        }
     ...
```

But when I am debugging it keeps stopping on the line *tiles[i] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tile);*
with the error *"Source not found."*

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are trying to use clones of the original ImageView rather than making new ones and setting their Image to be the same? I think the latter approach would be far easier. You can then call `layout.addView(tiles[i]);` to add the new ones to your layout.

Comment: @FoamyGuy May be he don't want to set all the properties or styles acquired by original imageview like height, widht,..etc for all of them programmatically.

Comment: @Pragnani possibly, and if that is the case then he can declare the ImageView in its on layout.xml file and then use LayoutInflater to create the new ones, that will make them all be pre-set to the desired configuration.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Yes...Agreed..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ImageView imageview=new ImageView(context);
```

`imageview=yourimageview`   // copy of your original

For your problem try this

```
View[] tiles = new ImageView[9];
ImageView testview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.testview);

for (int i = 0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
            tiles[i] = new Imageview(context);
        }
```

Comment: I used these changes, and no more error (yay!), but only the 9th instance (last element) of `tiles` shows up on the layout. I'm guessing this is because every element of `tiles` array points to the same object?

Comment: @AdamChoate Yeah...Take a separate layout with single imageview in it.. and then inflate the ImageView to get the copy of it.. and use that image..as FoamGuy Suggested

Comment: Do I have to create a new layout for every instance of the imageview? Could you show me how?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses :)  
Anyway I've opened a new question regarding how to inflate multiple view objects:
[How to inflate new copies of an ImageView object on a layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719674/how-to-inflate-new-copies-of-an-imageview-object-on-a-layout)

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. U r assigning tiles[i] twice. The instruction  "tiles[i] = new Imageview(context);"  should have no effect

Answer (score 2):

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
ImageView iv;
LinearLayout linear;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        iv.setPadding(0,0,0,20);
        linear.addView(iv);
    }
}
```

app view look like this
[app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMg1B.png)