# "Encasing" a map in a FrameLayout in an android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I'm trying to create a vertical LinearLayout of elements as follows:
A text view (weight 0.05)
A map (weight 0.85)
A horizontal layout of edit field and button

So far it seems OK, but now I'm trying to put the map within a FrameLayout so that I can append child views to it, but when I do so, the map no longer appears. Can anyone help?

My layout.xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/tlll"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".05"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="UK Map"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frlayout"
    android:layout_weight=".85"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:context=".MapShow" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:background="#004D79"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Enter address">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Find">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

The weights look fine, and it seems to be a problem with the layout heights and widths, but I can't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment width and height are zero. Try to increase them.

Comment: I tried experimenting by setting them both to "match_parent" (which makes sense as I want them to fill the FrameLayout) and I still get nothing :-(

Comment: Try to remove framelayout and put weight and height 0dp to <fragment > element

Comment: Normally i use ConstraintLayout. Weights don't work for me in complex layouts

Comment: This is what I had originally and it worked before I put FrameLayout in     

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".85"
            tools:context=".Mapper" />

Comment: So don't use Framelayout

Comment: I'm hoping to use the following method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719674/how-to-inflate-new-copies-of-an-imageview-object-on-a-layout) so I need some form of layout, and I need to stack views on top of it, and FrameLayout seems like a good way to go.

Comment: You can stack views on top of a view too. Having nested view groups is bad for performance https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MapsActivity" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:elevation="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_magnify"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/input_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_magnify"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Enter Address, City or Zip Code"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_gps"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map_location_db"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pin" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_location_db"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_datebase" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
   android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/relLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps" />

<ImageView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/place_picker"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_map" />

<ImageView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/place_info"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/place_picker"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_info" />
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Relative Layout. Will that enable me to place child views on top of the map?

Comment: which type of layout you want to achieve share with me the image

Comment: Its not an image, its either a text view, or an image view, which I will update with text/graphics depending on the map context (location etc.)

Comment: copy and paste my code and remove @drawable then you can easily understand and achieve what you want to do